# how to execute cmd as admin within a .reg file to change ownership

Tags: command-line, permissions, windows-registry, context-menu

I'm struggling to get this working properly.  This .reg when imported works on the surface, however upon execution im greeted with "This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object"

I presume this is due to the cmd not being launched as admin.  Can someone advise regarding alteration of the command?  I believe from past encounters with similar requirements you have to use powershell first to open the cmd or some such?

Here is the regfile

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RestoreOwnership]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Restore Ownership"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"NeverDefault"=""
"SubCommands"=""


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RestoreOwnership\Shell]


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RestoreOwnership\Shell\RestoreOwnershipSYSTEM]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Restore to System"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RestoreOwnership\Shell\RestoreOwnershipSYSTEM\command]
@="cmd.exe /c icacls \"%1\" /setowner \"SYSTEM\" /t /c & pause"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c icacls \"%1\" /setowner \"SYSTEM\" /t /c & pause"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RestoreOwnership\Shell\RestoreOwnershipTrustedInstaller]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Restore to TrustedInstaller"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RestoreOwnership\Shell\RestoreOwnershipTrustedInstaller\command]
@="cmd.exe /c icacls \"%1\" /setowner \"NT Service\\TrustedInstaller\" /t /c & pause"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c icacls \"%1\" /setowner \"NT Service\\TrustedInstaller\" /t /c & pause"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\RestoreOwnership]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Restore Ownership"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"NeverDefault"=""
"SubCommands"=""


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\RestoreOwnership\Shell]


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\RestoreOwnership\Shell\RestoreOwnershipSYSTEM]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Restore to System"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\RestoreOwnership\Shell\RestoreOwnershipSYSTEM\command]
@="cmd.exe /c icacls \"%1\" /setowner \"SYSTEM\" /t /c & pause"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c icacls \"%1\" /setowner \"SYSTEM\" /t /c & pause"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\RestoreOwnership\Shell\RestoreOwnershipTrustedInstaller]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Restore to TrustedInstaller"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\RestoreOwnership\Shell\RestoreOwnershipTrustedInstaller\command]
@="cmd.exe /c icacls \"%1\" /setowner \"NT Service\\TrustedInstaller\" /t /c & pause"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c icacls \"%1\" /setowner \"NT Service\\TrustedInstaller\" /t /c & pause"
```

Well, I have the SYSTEM one working

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RestoreOwnership]
"MUIVerb"="Restore Ownership"
"HasLUAShield"=""
"SubCommands"=""


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RestoreOwnership\shell\RestoreOwnershipSYSTEM]
@="Restore Ownership SYSTEM"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RestoreOwnership\shell\RestoreOwnershipSYSTEM\command]
@="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"SYSTEM\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""
"IsolatedCommand"="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"SYSTEM\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RestoreOwnership\shell\RestoreOwnershipTrustedInstaller]
@="Restore Ownership TrustedInstaller"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RestoreOwnership\shell\RestoreOwnershipTrustedInstaller\command]
@="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"NT Service\\TrustedInstaller\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""
"IsolatedCommand"="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"NT Service\\TrustedInstaller\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""
```

Unfortunately the TrustedInstaller one still falls on its face with

```
Invalid parameter "Service\TrustedInstaller"
```

I know it has to be something stupid simple im missing on that one.....

Comment: This is a clear X-Y problem. Please tell us, what is the problem you are trying to solve that lead you to try and use the registry to set or restore admin rights?

Comment: its ultimately a case of needing to temporarily take ownership of a folder and/or its files for various needs, and wanting to restore ownership via a means that are convenient to me.   Also for having access to it in the future.

It's purely for personal use.  I have a context menu entry to take ownership as well as one to restore inherited permissions, however having to go through and restore proper owner is taxing which means its often left un-done.  Ive had it present issues down the road after ive forgotten about such things.

Comment: Would it not be far easier to write a batch script that makes you owner, changes rights, then sets the owner rights to something else? You do of course need to run that file as administrator, but is far easier than all the trouble you are going through now.

Comment: I like my context menu entries, what can i say :)  Though being a rational human, I am nearing that point.  I have one more avenue to potentially pursue.  Use of the runas key can evidently force running as admin.

Comment: I had a similar adventure once. I was forced to move to Powershell to make my script go from non-admin to admin when executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final answer.   All revolved around formatting.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Ownership]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Ownership"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"NeverDefault"=""
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Ownership\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout01]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Take ownership"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout01\command]
@="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c takeown /f \\\"%1\\\" && icacls \\\"%1\\\" /grant *S-1-3-4:F /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""
"IsolatedCommand"="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c takeown /f \\\"%1\\\" && icacls \\\"%1\\\" /grant *S-1-3-4:F /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout02]
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Restore to administrators"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout02\command]
@="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"Administrators\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""
"IsolatedCommand"="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"Administrators\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout03]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Restore to system"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout03\command]
@="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"SYSTEM\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""
"IsolatedCommand"="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"SYSTEM\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout04]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Restore to trustedinstaller"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout04\command]
@="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"\"\"NT Service\\TrustedInstaller\"\"\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""
"IsolatedCommand"="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"\"\"NT Service\\TrustedInstaller\"\"\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Ownership]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Ownership"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"NeverDefault"=""
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Ownership\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout01]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Take ownership"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout01\command]
@="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c takeown /f \\\"%1\\\" && icacls \\\"%1\\\" /grant *S-1-3-4:F /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""
"IsolatedCommand"="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c takeown /f \\\"%1\\\" && icacls \\\"%1\\\" /grant *S-1-3-4:F /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout02]
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Restore to administrators"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout02\command]
@="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"Administrators\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""
"IsolatedCommand"="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"Administrators\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout03]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Restore to system"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout03\command]
@="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"SYSTEM\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""
"IsolatedCommand"="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"SYSTEM\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout04]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Restore to trustedinstaller"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Ownership\Shell\flyout04\command]
@="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"\"\"NT Service\\TrustedInstaller\"\"\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""
"IsolatedCommand"="powershell -windowstyle hidden -command \"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c icacls \\\"%1\\\" /setowner \"\"\"NT Service\\TrustedInstaller\"\"\" /t /c /l & pause' -Verb runAs\""
```